# What happens if no one has a low hand

Tags: omaha-hi-lo

If no one has 5 cards below or equal to 8, does everyone get 50% of their contribution back, or do only those who didn't fold share the low pot equally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no qualifying low, the full pot is awarded to the player(s) with the high hand.